# Javascript declarative/immutable version of 'maybe push'?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, immutability

I have code like this:

```
A = [1,2,3]
if (condition) {A.push(4)}
A.push(5)
```

But my array is actually immutable so I can't do that. How can I do it all in one expression? I don't want a null value in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```js
A = [1, 2, 3, ...(condition ? [4] : []), 5]
```

If this is common in your codebase, and you want to keep undefined then you write a filter function with a sentinel.

```js
const REMOVE = symbol('removeme')
const A = clean([1, 2, 3, condition ? 4 : REMOVE, 5])
function clean(arr) {return arr.filter(x=>x!==REMOVE)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Writer`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-2.2.2/docs/Control-Monad-Writer-Strict.html#t:Writer) monad here.

```js
// type Writer t a = { value :: a, array :: [t] }

// pure :: a -> Writer t a
const pure = (value) => ({ value, array: [] });

// bind :: (Writer t a, a -> Writer t b) -> Writer t b
const bind = (writerA, arrow) => {
    const writerB = arrow(writerA.value);
    const array = [...writerA.array, ...writerB.array];
    return { value: writerB.value, array };
};

// tell :: [t] -> Writer t ()
const tell = (array) => ({ value: undefined, array });

const writer = (gen) => {
    const next = (data) => {
        const { value, done } = gen.next(data);
        return done ? value : bind(value, next);
    };

    return next(undefined);
};

const example = (condition) => writer(function* () {
    yield tell([1, 2, 3]);
    if (condition) yield tell([4]);
    return tell([5]);
}());

console.log(example(true).array); // [1,2,3,4,5]
console.log(example(false).array); // [1,2,3,5]
```

Comment: This reminded me of the `Reap` and `Sow` pattern in mathematica so I also made a gist for that https://gist.github.com/qpwo/1a79842bd5ac416e4761a579182174fe . Love the haskell type comments – makes me see JS a different way.